# call function with multiple value kdb\q

Tags: kdb

I have a function declaration:

```
func:{[id;time] select last synp from synp_t where instr_id = id, tp_time < time}
```

where `instr_id` has type `i` and `tp_time` has type `v`.

For example, `func[8;05:00:11]` works fine and gives me value `17.55`.

However, if I try `func[8 1;05:00:11 07:10:59]`, I get:

```
'length ERROR: incompatible lengths (different lengths of operands for synchronized operation or table columns lengths are not the same
```

What I want to get is, for example, `17.55 9.66`.

Same error will pop up as well if I do `select res:func_demo[id;time]from tab`, where `tab` is table with two column of `instr_id` and `tp_time`.

I guess `enlist` could possibly resolve the problem, but I don't know exactly how to use it. How could I fix this issue?

Comment: please check the aj wiki before writing the queries around prevailing prices https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/aj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll recommend using [`aj`](https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/aj) to get the results, looking at your query it looks like you want the last price for the given `id` and smaller than the input `time`.

```
q)func:{[id;time] aj[`instr_id`tp_time; ([] instr_id:id;tp_time: time);synp_t]}
q)func[1 1 2;05:00:11 07:10:59 10:10:00]
```

with `each-both` you are calling the function n times and selecting the data n times.
**`aj` is one of the powerful features** Kdb provides for the `asof` prices.

Actually, you don't need `func` function, you can directly get the results using `aj`.

```
aj[`instr_id`tp_time; update instr_id:id, tp_time: time from tab;synp_t]
```

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your helps! aj works for me in this case! Thank you for your patients and answers! It is way faster than the repetitive function call!

Answer (score 5):

Both of the answers here are great but don't give much detail about why you got the `'length` error. The error was all down to your `where` clause `where instr_id = id, tp_time < time`. When you passed a list of items you actually created a list of boolean lists that are being passed to the where clause. Setting up two example lists to highlight this:

```
q)show instr_id:-5?10
2 8 0 1 6
q)show tp_time:5?.z.t
01:05:42.696 03:42:39.320 17:44:49.101 15:01:01.470 05:47:49.777
```

Running your first condition `instr_id = id` with atoms an lists:

```
q)instr_id=2
10000b
q)instr_id=2 8
'length
  [0]  instr_id=2 8
               ^
```

Using `=` will only work for an atom of a list of equal length to `instr_id`. If you want to pass multiple items to match you can instead use `in`:

```
q)instr_id in 2
10000b
q)instr_id in 2 8
11000b
```

For the second condition `tp_time < time` again requires atoms or lists of the same length to be passed:

```
q)tp_time<.z.t
11111b
q)tp_time<.z.t,.z.t
'length
  [0]  tp_time<.z.t,.z.t
              ^
```

Can get around this by making use of adverbs, such as each-right `/:` to compare `tp_time` to multiple items and using `any` to cut it down to a single list:

```
q)tp_time</:.z.t,.z.t
11111b
11111b
q)any tp_time</:.z.t,.z.t
11111b
```

Hope this helps you to understand where you ran into issues above.

Comment: Thanks so much! Learnt a lots from you!

Answer (score 4):

`func'[8 1;05:00:11 07:10:59]`should work

It uses the each both adverb which will apply the function between corresponding elements of the two input lists

More information about adverbs can be found here http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/. They are very powerful.

A lot of the inbuilt functions are able to take both atoms and lists as inputs and work accordingly, but with user defined functions you will most likely need to make use of adverbs to use them in a variety of situations

Comment: Thanks so much! If my result looks like, for example, `flip (enlist \`synp)!enlist enlist 17.55e`, how can I convert it to `17.55`..?

Comment: To extract values from a column you can use exec: `exec synp from <table>` or run ``<table>`synp``. Both of these return lists so if you only want an atom you will need to add `first`.